Partial Transpose of a 2×2×2 Density Matrix for a Three-Qubit System
I am working with a 2×2×2 density matrix that represents a three-qubit system. Could someone please help me to compute the partial transpose with respect to each qubit (A, B, and C) separately. Specifically, I would like to compute the partial transpose with respect to qubit B:
partialTranspose = ArrayFlatten@Map[Transpose, #, {2}] &;
mat = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, Cos[\[Theta]], 0, 
Cos[\[Theta]], 0, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 
Cos[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, Sin[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 
Sin[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 
Cos[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, Sin[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 
Sin[\[Theta]]^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0}};
(*Partition pour le sous-système A*) 
matA = Partition[mat, {4, 4}]; 
Row[MatrixForm /@ {mat, matA, partialTranspose@matA}, Spacer[10]]
(*Partition pour le sous-système C*) 
matC = Partition[mat, {2, 2}];  
Row[MatrixForm /@ {mat, matC, partialTranspose@matC}, Spacer[10]]


Your density matrix doesn't have trace = 1. You probably want to fix that!
